# How to use multiple groupBy and max in Groovy

Tags: groovy

I am trying to use the Groovy groupBy and max methods to summarise data in my list.

So far I have created a class named allowance which I use to build a list of allowances e.g.

```
class allowance {
      Integer StartDate
      Integer EndDate
      String  PayCode
      Integer CreatedOn
}

def lAllowances = [
    new allowance(StartDate: 20200330, EndDate: 99991231, PayCode: "PC_DFB1", CreatedOn: 20200330)
   ,new allowance(StartDate: 20200330, EndDate: 99991231, PayCode: "PC_DFB1", CreatedOn: 20200420)
   ,new allowance(StartDate: 20180405, EndDate: 20200329, PayCode: "PC_DFB1", CreatedOn: 20180125)
   ,new allowance(StartDate: 20200330, EndDate: 99991231, PayCode: "PC_DFB2", CreatedOn: 20200330)
   ,new allowance(StartDate: 20100405, EndDate: 99991231, PayCode: "PC_CAR1", CreatedOn: 20100103)
   ]
```

I now need to group this list and return the latest created allowance based upon CreatedOn for the grouping key (PayCode, StartDate).

I can get it to return what I need with one groupBy closure e.g.

```
lAllowances.groupBy {it.PayCode}.collectEntries {[(it.key): it.value.max {it.CreatedOn}]}.each{ k,v ->
    mAllowances.put (iCount, [StartDate: v.StartDate, EndDate: v.EndDate, PayCode: k])
    iCount++
}
```

but when I specify a second closure the max method doesn't seem to work or at least it doesn't return what I thought it would e.g.

```
lAllowances.groupBy ({it.PayCode},{it.StartDate}).collectEntries {[(it.key): it.value.max {it.CreatedOn}]}.each{ k,v ->
    mAllowances.put (iCount, [StartDate: v.StartDate, EndDate: v.EndDate, PayCode: k])
    iCount++
}
```

The expected result set after grouping based upon the data above would be something like:

```
PayCode: "PC_DFB1", StartDate: 20200330, EndDate: 99991231, CreatedOn: 20200420
PayCode: "PC_DFB1", StartDate: 20180405, EndDate: 20200329, CreatedOn: 20180125
PayCode: "PC_DFB2", StartDate: 20200330, EndDate: 99991231, CreatedOn: 20200330
PayCode: "PC_CAR1", StartDate: 20100405, EndDate: 99991231, CreatedOn: 20100103
```

Any help you can give to resolve this would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: sounds like you want to sort the list... not to group

Comment: Besides the printout of the expected result, can you describe what you were trying to do in your second example? The seconds code example doesn't make sense or translate to anything near what the expected output looks like

Comment: @daggett yes sorting has definitely helped.  Thank you.

Comment: @pczeus I was trying to group the data on PayCode and StartDate and for each combination return the row that corresponds to the maximum createdon date.  In effect performing some sort of deduplication so that I only had one row for each pay code/start combination.  Then for each row I would add it to a new map and iterate over it later in the script.  Although this step may be superfluous.  As you can tell my Groovy skills are quite limited :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can concatenate the fields to group by, and then collect with the max closure for each of the matches

```
def result = lAllowances.groupBy { it.StartDate + it.PayCode }
                        .collect { def matchKey, def matches -> 
                            return matches.max { it.CreatedOn }
                        }
```

this returns your described result.

If there is a risk of the concatenation creating false matches (e.g `1 + 11` and `11 + 1`), you can insert a separator character like `|` in between.

Comment: Thank you.  That does exactly what I wanted.